# React Hook to display all boxes checked on a form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I've created a form and am saving the data to a json file locally. I can save all the data except for the questions with multiple selections and multiple checkboxes. It only saves the last one selected. I am trying to write a switch statement within a React Hook that is working to help save the submitted form. I keep getting an error "cannot identify type of undefined." I'm new to react and don't know what to do from here.

This is in my hooks folder:

```
export const useInputChange = (customValue, callback) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(customValue ? customValue : "" || []);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    var newValue;
    switch (customValue.type) {
      case "multipleSelection":
        newValue = $("multipleSelection").find("option:checked");
        break;
      case "checkboxChoice":
        newValue = $("checkboxChoice").find("input:checked");
        break;
      default:
        newValue = event.target.value;
    }
    setValue(newValue);
    if (callback) {
      callback(event.target.name, newValue);
    }
  };
  return {
    value: value,
    handleChange: handleChange
  };
};
```

This is my callback in my components folder:

```
const callback = (name, value) => {
  console.log("callback", name, value);
  inlineData[name] = value;
  setInlineData(inlineData);
  console.log(inlineData);
};
```

The jquery works in the console to pull up the correct arrays.

This is the component:

```
export const Survey = (props) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [isFinalPage, setIsFinalPage] = useState(false);
  const [surveyValues, setSurveyValues] = useState({});
  const [loadedInputs, setLoadedInputs] = useState({});
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState({});
  const [inlineData, setInlineData] = useState({});

  const { surveyId } = props;

  const triggerBackendUpdate = () => {
    console.log(question);
    console.log(surveyValues);
    setPage(1);
    setSurveyValues({});
    setQuestion({});
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    if (surveyId) {
     const inputDataFile = import(`./data_${surveyId}.json`);
     inputDataFile.then((response) => {
     setLoadedInputs(response.default);
      });
    }
  });

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.persist();
    for (let formInput of event.target.elements) {
      const isText = isTextInput(formInput.type);
      console.log(formInput);
      if (isText) {
        surveyValues[formInput.name] = formInput.value;
        question[formInput.question] = formInput.question;
      }

      if (formInput.type === "selectMultiple") {
        let selected = [].filter.call(
          formInput.options,
          (option) => option.selected
        );
        console.log(formInput);
        console.log(selected);
        console.log(formInput.options.selected);

        const values = selected.map((option) => option.value);
        surveyValues[formInput.name] = values;
        question[formInput.name] = formInput.question;
     }

      if (formInput.type === "checkbox") {
        surveyValues[formInput.name] = formInput.value;
        question[formInput.name] = formInput.question;
      }
    }

    setQuestion(question);

    setSurveyValues(surveyValues);
    const nextPage = page + 1;
    const inputs = props.inputs
      ? props.inputs.filter((inputOption) => inputOption.page === 
          nextPage): [];

    if (isFinalPage) {
      triggerBackendUpdate();
    } else {
      if (inputs.length === 0) {
        setIsFinalPage(true);
      } else {
        setPage(nextPage);
      }
    }
  };

  const callback = (name, value) => {
    console.log("callback", name, value);
    inlineData[name] = value;
    setInlineData(inlineData);
    console.log(inlineData);
  };

  const saveSurvey = async () => {
    await fetch("/api/survey", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(inlineData),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  };

  const inputs = props.inputs
    ? props.inputs.filter((inputOption) => inputOption.page === page)
    : [];
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {isFinalPage !== true &&
        inputs.map((obj, index) => {
          let inputKey = `input-${index}-${page}`;

          return obj.type === "radio" || obj.type === "checkbox" ? (
            <SurveyRadioInput
              object={obj}
              type={obj.type}
              required={props.required}
              triggerCallback={callback}
              question={obj.question}
              defaultValue={obj.defaultValue}
              name={obj.name}
              key={inputKey}
            />
          ) : obj.type === "checkbox" ? (
            <SurveyCheckboxInput
              object={obj}
              type={obj.type}
              required={props.required}
              triggerCallback={callback}
              question={obj.question}
              defaultValue={obj.defaultValue}
              name={obj.name}
              key={inputKey}
            />
          ) : obj.type === "select" ? (
            <SurveySelectInput
              className="form-control mb-3 mt-3"
              object={obj}
              type={obj.type}
              question={obj.question}
              required={props.required}
              triggerCallback={callback}
              defaultValue={obj.defaultValue}
              name={obj.name}
              key={inputKey}
            />
          ) : obj.type === "selectMultiple" ? (
            <SurveySelectMultipleInput
              className="form-control mb-3 mt-3"
              object={obj}
              type={obj.type}
              question={obj.question}
              required={props.required}
              triggerCallback={callback}
              defaultValue={obj.defaultValue}
              name={obj.name}
              key={inputKey}
            />
          ) : (
            <SurveyTextInput
              className="mb-3 mt-3 form-control"
              object={obj}
              type={obj.type}
              question={props.question}
              required={props.required}
              triggerCallback={callback}
              placeholder={obj.placeholder}
              defaultValue={obj.defaultValue}
              name={obj.name}
              key={inputKey}
            />
          );
        })}

      {isFinalPage !== true ? (
        <button name="continue-btn" className="btn btn-primary my-5 mx-5">
          Continue
        </button>
      ) : (
        <Link to="/thankyou">
          <button
            onClick={saveSurvey}
             type="button"
            className="btn btn-primary my-5 mx-5"
          >
            Submit Survey
           </button>
         </Link>
      )}
    </form>
  );
};
```

This is in my inputs folder:

```
export const SurveySelectMultipleInput = (props) => {
  const { object } = props;
  const { value, handleChange } = useInputChange(
    props.defaultValue,
    props.triggerCallback
  );
  const inputType = isTextInput(props.type) ? props.type : "";
  const inputProps = {
    className: props.className ? props.className : "form-control",
    onChange: handleChange,
    value: value,
    required: props.required,
    question: props.question,
    type: inputType,
    name: props.name ? props.name : `${inputType}_${props.key}`,
  };
  console.log(value);
  return (
    <>
      <div id={object.name}>
        <h5>{props.question}</h5>
        <select
          {...inputProps}
          name={object.name}
          className={props.className}
          multiple={object.multiple}
        >
          <option hidden value>
            Select one
          </option>
          {object.options.map((data, index) => {
            return (
              <option
                value={data.value}
                id={`${object.name}-${index}`}
                key={`${object.type}-${index}`}
                className={`form-check ${props.optionClassName}`}
              >
                {data.label}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you post the component you're using this hook with? Also, when querying elements built by React, it's recommended to use `ref`.

Comment: @kaveh I added the component

Comment: I don't see `useInputChange` in your component. Where is being used?

Comment: @kaveh I added the input where `useInputChange` is being used.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly how your components and hooks behave without having an example showing their behavior and properties. Regardless, I made some assumptions and tried to answer:

First of all, what is the expected type of `customValue` in `useInputChange`? Are you expecting a string or an array? Then what is the `type` attribute on it that you're checking in your `switch` statement?

As for the jquery selector, what is `multipleSelection`? Is it the class name you're using for your select elements? Then your selector must start with a dot a/nd then you can get the value by calling `.val` method on the selected element:

`newValue = $(".multipleSelection").val();`

Here's a working example for multiple select elements, using your code: https://codepen.io/kaveh/pen/QWNNQMV

Note that I had to assign an arbitrary `type` attribute to `VALUE` to get it working with your switch statement.

All that being said, as I mentioned in my comment, it's recommended to use `ref` to access elements created by React and not other query selectors such as those you get from jquery.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref